# Pass variable from PHP into HTML

Tags: php, html, variables

I've got a simple .php file with Rock, Paper, Scissors game (some schoolwork) that tracks your score and a `.html` file with buttons to choose from R/P/S.

Score is tracked via session variable, is there a simple way to pass the value of this variable and display it on the html page?

Comment: After the <body> tag : `<?php echo $_SESSION[ "my_var" ]; ?>`. By the way, you should change your profile image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generate your HTML page from PHP file too. That's how php works. That way you can print out PHP variables. HTML is no programming language - it's just markup language...like ...hmmm..XML.

Answer (score 1):

You can add addhandler in `.htaccess` for html files to treat it as php file, see example:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

but instead you can, avoid above and change the file extension from `.html` to `.php` you can pass it as query string [GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), see example below:

```
http://example.com/myphppage.php?key=value
```

or you can access `session` by adding [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at starting of page

Comment: *"The answer is NO. You cannot get PHP Variables in HTML"* - That's not entirely true. You can instruct Apache to treat `.html|.htm` files as PHP files.

Comment: Sidenote: that's not my downvote.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the hint, answer updated accordingly! no prob :)

Comment: You're welcome, you should have marked your edit about treating html files as php *as an edit*. People who visit your answer may think why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: Usually when making a mistake, you mark an edit as an edit, and possibly using the `<strike>code/text</strike>` tags on the originally posted code/text that you may have a made a mistake. That tells the community that, well..  you made a mistake. Everybody makes mistakes, even I do at times. If we didn't make them, we wouldn't have learned anything, *right?* ;-) *cheers*

Comment: Agree! will keep in mind, and follow as well

Answer (score 0):

If you save your `.html` file as a `.php` file, you can do this quite easily by adding

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?>
```

into your HTML.  For example:

```
<p><?php echo $_SESSION['score']; ?></p>
```